# The Bootstrap displays input with lg size a much larger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, sass

When I build form with Bootstrap horizontal style

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Large label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputLarge" placeholder="Large input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Small label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall" placeholder="Small input">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The result is not correct:

Input with "lg" size has height: 68 px

This is my large input:
[image]

This is normal large input:
[image]

I use:

- sass 3.2.19
- sass-rails 4.0.5
- sprockets-rails 2.2.2
- bootstrap-sass 3.3.1.0
- rails 4.2.0

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you expect?

Comment: I want to create the correct form with Bootstrap input size class.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the appropriate `input-xx` class to each of the inputs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Large label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="formGroupInputLarge" placeholder="Large input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Small label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall" placeholder="Small input">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: According to the official documentation, if I use a horizontal form, then the "input-lg" class is not needed